# VS Code debugger not stoping at breakpoints

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have just started to use VS Code. I am using python and I have encountered in some problems when it comes to debugging.

I have read other topics but my situation differs a bit. Debugging works perfectly, if I have some simple test application, although I am currently working with serial communication so I am importing serial library.

The debugger will not stop at any of the breakpoints.

**launch.json Debugger settings**

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Terminal (integrated)",
        "type": "python",
        "program": "${file}",
        "request": "launch",
        "logToFile": true,
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
```

**code that can be debugged**

```
   import math

   print("hello")

   i = 5 *breakpoint*

   print(5)
```

**code where debugger won't stop on break points**

```
  import serial
  import io     *breakpoint*

  ser = serial.Serial(  
     port='COM10',
     baudrate=2400,
     parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
     stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
     bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
     )

     print("test") *breakpoint*

     ser.write(b'D Hallo \r\n')
     print(f'command: {command}, text: {text}')5
     ser.close()  

     print(5)
```

The debugging project is the same and debugger does not write something different when executing it. I have installed Code Runner and Python extensions.

What could be possible cause of the problem and what could fix it?

Comment: You specified two breakpoint locations; does the code not stop on either? Regardless, I would file at bug at https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd.

Comment: Indeed, will do. Thanks for your replay.